# Help With a Switch

Tags: switches

I am trying to replace a broken switch that controls the rolling up and down of a window on my car. I have the control module out, it looks like this:

[image]

The "auto" switch connection on rolling up has been broken. I know this because it rolls down fine, and when I press the switch up and short the switch terminals, the window rolls up.

Anyway, I was trying to replace the switch with an on-off-on DPDT switch, but I realized that the original switch isn't wired that way. Here is my drawing of the original switch connections.
[image]

So as you can see, it acts more like two ON-ON switches than one On-OFF-ON. My question: Is there a way to manipulate the wiring on a normal switch to get this behavior while still using the one switch, or is there a switch that has this behavior that I don't know about?

I was thinking about alternate solutions. I might be able to make it work with two On-On switches, but it would be a bit confusing to work with if someone didn't know how to operate the window. Thoughts?

Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The easiest way? Junk yard or Ebay for an original switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer because I don't know what switches are available to you but the original is probably wired as sketched below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fih3yQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Switch and motor circuit. (When will CircuitLab give us a motor symbol?)*

Motor direction depends on which contact is actuated.

You could use two SPDT switches to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! Fortunately, I managed to repair the switch myself. I took it apart and one of the contacts was layered with a black crust. I scraped it off, put it together, and it works like new!

Comment: Did you put some contact lubricant on the cleaned contacts?